# Null byte files in duplicity backup

Tags: backup, troubleshooting, duplicity

When duplicty encounters 0-byte-files it gives an IO-error:
`Error [Errno 5] Input/output error` ... `getting delta for` ...

The files are usually some wired stuff like

```
/home/user/.libreoffice/3/user/fR6Qeq
/home/user/.config/dconf/user.Z18ABW
/home/user/.mozilla/firefox/profile/sessionstore-8.js
```

I feel that this slows down the backup process significantly. So what's the best way to deal with that problem?

Comment: Are you using the latest (0.6.21) version of duplicity?  Lots of bugs get fixed with each incremental release.

Comment: @Flup Yes I am using 0.6.21

Comment: I usually get that error message (in duplicity 0.7) when the file is unreadable by the current user. Do you have read permissions?